# CurrencyIsoCode change not updating Currency field in record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a record-edit-form, where I have 2 fields (for testing purposes). The fields are CurrencyIsoCode and a custom field Budget__c (Currency Field).

What I have noticed; if you change the Currency in the CurrencyIsoCode, it doesn't update the Currency symbol in the Budget field.

Is anyone aware if how this should be done? I am exposing the form on an Experience Site.

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Lead">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="CurrencyIsoCode" />
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Budget__c" />
    <lightning-button label="Submit" type="submit"></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

When reading up on how the currency symbol is set it mentions that it takes the orgs default/Users set currency and places the symbol in this field, but it seems a bit mad that it would do this and ignore the fact that you have updated the Currency field to something else.

Is anyone aware of how to update this? It's causing a bit of an issue.